# How can i prevent an android dialog from dismiss when user press beside the dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

I have an Dialog (not an AlertDialog) which should only be dismissed when user press a button. 
But in my case, the dialog dismiss also when user press beside the dialog.
How can i avoid that. 
Thnx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

where `dialog` is your `Dialog` variable

[Dialog docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

Comment: thnx!exactly what i'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel) or 
setCancelable(boolean flag)

These are the methods that you can use to prevent Dialog from being dismissed

Answer (score 0):

Set the cancelable state to false using this: '.setCalcelable(false)'

So your dialog code would look something like this...

Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this);
mDialog.setCancelable(false);